# Is there a way to hide a displayed object using IPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, display

I am using the IPython module in a Jupyter Notebook.
I am using the display module to display buttons.

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
import IPython.display as dsply
def click_reset(b):
    print("reset domains button")
    restoreDomains()

resetButton = widgets.Button(description="Reset Domains")
resetButton.on_click(click_reset)
dsply.display(resetButton)
```

This works fine, but I am trying to find a way to programatically hide certain buttons. Based off the execution of my other code, I want certain buttons to be removed from the UI. Is there anything like `hide(resetButton)` that I can use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [hide a widget](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/674#issuecomment-233566026) using

```
resetButton.layout.visibility = 'hidden'
```

to let the widget still consume space, or

```
resetButton.layout.display = 'none'
```

to let the widget not consume space anymore.

The top-level attribute `resetButton.visible = False` is not longer supported.

Comment: To make the item visible again use
`resetButton.layout.visibility = 'visible'`  
or  
`resetButton.progress_bar.layout.display = None`  (Yes, that#s quite confusing.)

Answer (score 7):

When I use @SergeyGornostaev's answer, I still have a residual cross showing up on the left side of the cell output. I found the following command removes the widget all together:

```
resetButton.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide every widget by setting it's property `visible` to `False`

```
resetButton.visible = False
```